# Integrating Instant Messaging into SharePoint!

Tags: sharepoint, instant-message

Maybe this is a dumb question!

I'm just wandering is there any way/web part integrating with SharePoint, by which I can communicate with others instantly.

The reason behind this requirement is that I still have not found any workaround to communicate with my colleagues instantly, like MSN, in SharePoint.

P.s If I start building one, where should I get started!

Thanks for your input and forgive me if my question is stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users who run Windows Live Messenger will get a precense icon for all user lookups when their email settings are configured properly. It requires all users to add each other to their live accounts, so it might not be the solution you are looking for. Another way to get the precense icon is by using Microsoft Office Communications Server as Moo suggested.

This also integrates well into Outlook and is the way Microsoft decided to implement communication in the Office suit.

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate [Microsoft Office Communcations Server](http://www.microsoft.com/communicationsserver/en/gb/default.aspx) into SharePoint apparently.  Gives you access to MSN Messenger internally to your enterprise, among other things.

Comment: It's not that easy of an integration (server side setup I mean), but the features are pretty good, because they are designed to work well together.

Comment: I like the presence awareness in SharePoint - that's a pretty neat bit of the integration.

Answer (score 0):

Check out chatterbox:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/05/15/chatterbox-persistent-chat-session-for-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is another open source feature I have been working on.

EDIT: The name of the feature is Sharepoint Messenger. You can find it either google search, codeplex or the link below.

https://sharepointmessenger.codeplex.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have thought about that. Updated.